# Variables inside jQuery .on() not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so I have a jQuery .on() function that looks like this....

```
$("#grid").on('rowdoubleclick', function(event) {

    var appData = $("#grid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
    var appID = appData.application_id                                                                     

    var cellClassTitle = function(row, column, value) {

        alert("VALUE: " + value + " appData.title: " + appData.title);
        if (value == appData.title) 
           {
            return "yellowCell"
            }
    }});
```

My problem is that the appData.title variable inside the cellClassTitle function only gets evaluated once, on the first doubleclick. the appData variable outside the cellClassTitle function evaluates each time a row is doubleclicked but the appData.title value inside remains the same. How can I get it to update each time the .on('rowdoubleclick') function executes?

Comment: Where are you actually invoking the `cellClassTitle` function?

Comment: it returns the css class name for rows/cells in my grid upon updating the grids data source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function outside the scope of the rowdoubleclick handler, e.g.

```
var appData = appData || {title:""};
var cellClassTitle = function(row, column, value) {

    alert("VALUE: " + value + " appData.title: " + appData.title);
    if (value == appData.title) 
    {
      return "yellowCell"
    }
}

$("#grid").on('rowdoubleclick', function(event) {

    appData = $("#grid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
    var appID = appData.application_id

});
```

Disclaimer: this is nasty, take care not to pollute the global scope! http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/

Comment: appData is then undefined at the time you define the function

Comment: @A.O. it only matters if the function is invoked before it is defined

Comment: Actually there is a point here. It doesn't matter that `appData` is not defined when the method is defined, but it does matter that `appData` is limited to the scope of the `rowdoubleclick` handler. You would need to define `appData` at the same time as cellClassTitle, and then lose the "var" prefix within the handler for this to work.

Comment: BUT (and it's a big but), this points to major architectural problems where you're relying on global scope, which common sense, and Crockford says you almost certainly shouldn't polute: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/

Comment: @MrJamin all I had to do was define appData outside the .on() handler and remove the "var" inside, I can still define the cellClassName function inside. This little snippet is only used to highlight a certain row in one of my many grids, is it really that critical to not define appData outside of the handlers scope?

Comment: @A.O. yes, it's that crucial - read "Javascript: the good parts". You will get a performance gain by defining the function outside the click handler, otherwise you'll have multiple, scope-bound declarations. if my answer was helpful, please upvote and/or accept!

Comment: @MrJamin ok i get why you wouldnt want the function to be re-declared everytime the .on() executes, but it's not the end of the world to have a few global variables for situations like this right?...also thanks for the global domination article, im going to adopt YAHOO's global object trick....

Comment: It depends, it makes for brittle code that'll break easily if you're not careful or there are many people working on it.